# tk_messageBox locks out interaction with base window, in linux environment

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

[image]In my automation framework, I pause the script on failure by launching a `tk_messageBox`. But in Linux environment when message box pops-up I am unable to interact with base window (scrolling, button press, etc.).

But no such issue are reported with Windows.

Sample code:

```
toplevel .top
button .top.b -text "check" -command {tk_messageBox -type ok -message "hello"}
place .top.b -in .top -relx 0.0 -rely 0.0 -relwidth 0.2 -relheight 0.2
```

When I press the check button, "hello" message box appears but now I can not click the check button again till the time message box exists in Linux only. But in Windows I can click button as many time i want, which launches multiple text boxes.

Comment: I don't understand why you've had no issues reported with Windows. I expected that tk_messageBox was modal on windows, and when I checked just now, I found that it was.

Comment: _“I pause the script on failure by launching a tk_messageBox”_ Well don't do that. (Also, what is the question?)

Comment: @DonalFellows: Take it this way, that I have a GUI, from where I am launching a pop-up window using tk_messageBox. But till the time pop-up window exist I can't interact with the parent window, specifically in linux

Comment: @nurdglaw For we tk_message box is working as modal on linux but modeless on windows. Can I make in modeless in linux too. Sample code added in the question. Attaching output screen shot for windows. Want same in linux.

I am tcl 8.6.4

Comment: Very curious. When I run your code it behaves (to my mind incorrectly) as you describe. If I modify it to use . (the root window), the message box is modal (which to my mind is correct). I'm not sure whether you are looking for consistency between platforms or looking for non-modal behaviour on Linux. Whichever, this is the moment for me to back away and leave others, such as @DonalFellows, to investigate/assist further. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, the mysteries of the changing modality of dialogs on Windows.